# Patrick Henry Quote

Tags: history

What does the following quote mean ?

> The battle, sir is not to the strong alone; it is to the vigilant, the active, the brave.

Comment: It's an allusion to Ecclesiastes: [The race is not to the swift or the battle to the strong...](http://biblehub.com/ecclesiastes/9-11.htm) Henry just means the outcome of battles depends not only on the *strength* of the opposing armies - to win, an army must also be vigilant, active, and brave.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ...also it makes the underdog feel better, like they have a chance against much greater odds.

Comment: Why did a web search not answer it?

Answer (score 1):

In Patrick Henry's famous "Give me liberty or give me death!" speech, his quote "The battle, sir is not to the strong alone; it is to the vigilant, the active, the brave." Relates, in part, to the "team effort" of war, that team is not just comprised of the physically able, but the brave, watchful, and motivated. You don't have to be physically strong to help win a battle.

Answer (score 0):

A more full quotation is:

> We are not weak if we make a proper use of those means which the God
>   of Nature has placed in our power... the battle, sir, is not to the
>   strong alone it is to the vigilant, the active, the brave.

To be achieve victory, one's own ability is not the only thing needed. One also have to be watchful, willing to act, and have the courage to engage in a struggle.

The idea can be even more generic than  a war or conflict. We all see people who are geniuses working dead-end jobs or failing classes because they do not apply themselves. The same is true here. Not only do you have to have the ability to succeed, but you have to apply yourself to succeed as well.

Therefore, evaluate yourself based on your natural talents and then be watchful for when those talents can be used. And when they are useful, act - no matter how scared you may be.